# Parsing more than 2 GB XML file with SAX: exception: Internal Error: fPreviousChunk == NULL

Tags: java, xml-parsing, saxparser

We are getting the below exception parsing a 2 GB XML file, We found that, this is a known issue from apache. What are the other available options to parsing a  big XML?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal Error: fPreviousChunk == NULL
at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:1094)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:345)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:223)
```

Sax version is
2009 xercesImpl-2.2.1.jar
2009 xerces.jar

What about STAX? DOM vs Streaming

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/SJSXP2.html

References
http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t165629-any-parser-can-handle-2-1gb-file.html

So  can we assume the below?
SAX parser WILL not handle files more than 2 GB sizes.
true or false?

Thanks

Comment: did you try the sax parser included with the jdk?

Comment: I am not getting; What do you mean? The jars that we are using are as below: Sax version is 2009 xercesImpl-2.2.1.jar 2009 xerces.jar

Thanks

Comment: java already comes with a SAX parser.  i'm wondering if you have tried that instead of a specific version of xercesImpl?

Comment: If you have an Apache bug report that says it won't work, and that bug report does also say "fixed," then yes, it's safe to assume that the Xerces SAX parser won't handle files greater than 2 GB (I say "if" because you haven't actually linked to the bug report).

Comment: As for StAX: I've read and written files that are in the dozens of gigabytes range using it.

Comment: Yes, we are using the one included in Javax

Answer (score 0):

Today, I also met this problem. Here is how I resolved it. First, I found this error popup from Xerces version 1.2.3. So I tried to upgrade to 1.4.4 which is latest for version 1. However, it will pop up this error when parsing about 80,000 records. Later, I just removed this dependency, that means it will use the Xerces bundles with JDK. And it WORKS. So the root cause is out-of-dated `xerces` library.